# OSGI bundle status grace period

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, opendaylight, apache-aries

I am trying to install two bundles on Karaf. For one of the bundle i am getting error and when I see the bundle:diag i got below message. It is the same thing compaining in logs also. Similar kind of bundle already deploy and it has the same dependencies.  first one is working but the for second bundle i am getting below error.  any thoughts?

opendaylight-user@root>bundle:diag

### videoweb (421)

Status: GracePeriod
Blueprint
2/10/16 6:07 PM
Missing dependencies: 
(objectClass=org.osgi.service.http.HttpService)

2016-02-10 23:54:07.113 GMT+00:00 [Blueprint Extender: 3] ERROR o.a.a.b.c.BlueprintContainerImpl - Unable to start blueprint container for bundle com.xyz.videosdn.tesweb due to unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=org.osgi.service.http.HttpService)]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:336) [org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48) [org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.0]

Answer (score 5):

The error means that your bundle has a mandatory reference to a service with the interface **org.osgi.service.http.HttpService**.

So you need to install a bundle that provides this service. In karaf this service is normally provided by pax-web. It can be installed using:

```
feature:install http
```